Access Root Element in UWP
I want in UWP to make like Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPage from Metro.
To do this, I decided to make a SplitView:

SplitView splitView = new SplitView();
splitView.Name = "FavoriteSplitView";
splitView.DisplayMode = SplitViewDisplayMode.Overlay;
splitView.IsPaneOpen = true;
splitView.OpenPaneLength = 300;
splitView.PanePlacement = SplitViewPanePlacement.Right;
splitView.CompactPaneLength = 0;

Frame frame = new Frame();

splitView.Pane = new FavoriteControl();
splitView.Content = frame;

How can I append it to the root element?
The problem is that this code is runned inside a Frame, so if I put a Name on the Main Grid and append the splitView inside the Main Grid, the size will be the frame size, which I don't want
I tried a lot of things with Window.Current.Content, like setting it as a Grid, but It returned null.
I tried too to do Window.Current.Content = splitView, which works very well, but all my app UI was gone.

To help me understand this problem, could you please show the xaml code? or take a screenshot and explain where you want the SplitView to be and what size it should be.

I don't have the XAML now, but: In MainPage.XAML, there is a Frame that point to UI/NavigationRailFrame. The SplitView code is in UI/NavigationRailFrame.XAML.CS. I want SplitView to be with MainPage

I think this should be impossible, SplitView can only be used with control objects, and cannot add the entire page.
